# Using amcharts3 with reactjs cannot display graph

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

I am trying to make an API request (GET) then the received data should be appended on the graph as a statistatics , this is my code when i run it i got nothing on the graph .
I am trying to make an API request (GET) then the received data should be appended on the graph as a statistatics , this is my code when i run it i got nothing on the graph.
I am trying to make an API request (GET) then the received data should be appended on the graph as a statistatics , this is my code when i run it i got nothing on the graph.
I am trying to make an API request (GET) then the received data should be appended on the graph as a statistatics , this is my code when i run it i got nothing on the graph

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AmCharts from "@amcharts/amcharts3-react";
import {Bar, Doughnut, Line, Pie, Polar, Radar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {CardColumns, Card, CardHeader, CardBody,Row, Col, Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter} from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import Modals from '../Notifications/Modals/Modals.js';
import RangedDatePicker from '../DatePicker/RangedDatePicker.js';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import ButtonDropdowns from '../Buttons/ButtonDropdowns/ButtonDropdowns.js';



let loginPath = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reactions/daily';

let config = { 
  headers: {   
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token') 
  },
  mode: 'no-cors'
};



function generateData() {
   var successDataCount=[];
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reactions/daily?from=2017-01-01 &to=2018-06-04 ', config)
        .then((response )=> {
             
              for(let i=0 ; i<response.data[0].reactions.length;i++)
              { 
                var year =response.data[0].reactions[i].year;
                var month =response.data[0].reactions[i].month;
                var day =response.data[0].reactions[i].day;
                var dateOfReaction = new Date(year,month,day);
                var count = response.data[0].reactions[i].count;

                successDataCount.push({date:dateOfReaction ,count:count });
              }
              

               
                var firstDate = new Date();

                var dataProvider = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                  var date = new Date(firstDate.getTime());

                  date.setDate(i);

                  dataProvider.push({
                    date: date,
                    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
                  });
                }
                console.log(dataProvider)

                return dataProvider;
             
  })

  .catch((error) => console.log(error))

  


  
}




class Charts extends Component {

 constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    const minDate = new Date();
    const maxDate = new Date();
    minDate.setFullYear(minDate.getFullYear() - 1);
    minDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    maxDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    this.state = {
    dataProvider: [],
    timer: null,
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    autoOk: false,
  };



    this.handleChangeMinDate = this.handleChangeMinDate.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeMaxDate= this.handleChangeMaxDate.bind(this)
    this.getTimeRangeFromCalendar = this.getTimeRangeFromCalendar.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount() {


 
      // Update the chart dataProvider every 3 seconds
     
        this.setState({
          dataProvider: generateData()
        });
  



}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.state.timer);
}

//Getting StartDate and EndDate from calendar to update charts
getTimeRangeFromCalendar(range){

  let from = JSON.stringify(range.startDate._d);
  let to = JSON.stringify(range.endDate._d);

  
  console.log('*************************CHOISEN STATISTICS*************************')
  let config = { 
    headers: {   
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token') 
    },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    params :{
      from: from,
      to: to
    }

  };

  console.log(config.params)  
  console.log(config.params.to) 
  
  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reactions/daily', { 
    headers: {   
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token') 
    },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    params :{
      from: from,
      to: to
    }

  } )
  .then((response )=> console.log(response.data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))


}



  handleChangeMinDate(event, date) {
    this.setState({
      minDate: date,
    } , function(){console.log(this.state.minDate)});
  };

  handleChangeMaxDate(event, date) {
    this.setState({
      maxDate: date,
    });
  };

render() {
 const config = {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 40,
  "marginLeft": 40,
  "autoMarginOffset": 20,
  "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true
  }],
  "balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 1,
    "shadowAlpha": 0
  },
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "balloon":{
      "drop": true,
      "adjustBorderColor": false,
      "color":"#ffffff"
    },
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bulletSize": 5,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "title": "red line",
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "valueField": "value",
    "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
  }],
  "chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "oppositeAxis": false,
    "offset":30,
    "scrollbarHeight": 80,
    "backgroundAlpha": 0,
    "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
    "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
    "graphFillAlpha": 0,
    "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
    "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
    "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
    "autoGridCount": true,
    "color":"#AAAAAA"
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "pan": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "cursorAlpha":1,
    "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
    "limitToGraph":"g1",
    "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
    "valueZoomable": true
  },
  "valueScrollbar":{
    "oppositeAxis": false,
    "offset":50,
    "scrollbarHeight":10
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
  },
  "dataProvider": this.state.dataProvider
};
return (

  <div className="animated fadeIn">
  <CardColumns className="cols-2 column-count-1">
  <Row>
  <Col>
  <Card>
  <CardHeader>
  <i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Choosing parameters
  </CardHeader>
  <CardBody>


  <MuiThemeProvider>
  <RangedDatePicker  sendMinDate={this.handleChangeMinDate} sendMaxDate= {this.handleChangeMaxDate}/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  <ButtonDropdowns/>



  </CardBody>
  </Card>
  </Col>
  </Row>



  <Card>
  <CardHeader>
  Statistics
  <div className="card-actions">
  <a href="http://www.chartjs.org">
  <small className="text-muted">docs</small>
  </a>
  </div>
  </CardHeader>
  <CardBody>

  <div className="App">

  <AmCharts.React style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }} options={config} />
  </div>
  </CardBody>
  </Card>


  </CardColumns>
  </div>

  )
}
}

export default Charts;
```

and this is the error when i clicked on the graph ........................

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDCEa.png)

Comment: Can you at least post fiddle containing your chart code and how you're assigning this data to it? Hard to tell what's wrong with this snippet alone.

Comment: hey xorspark , i edit the code there u can find the component Chart.js

Comment: I'm no react expert, but generateData() is not returning the array - it's returning undefined due to the async request (the `return` in `then` isn't working like you think it is). You should set the state when you get the data in your `then` method, which likely means moving that inside your Charts class.